# jQuery .delay() in animation loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to do some basic animation with jQuery. I want to fade in a few elements, but I would like to fade in, the 2nd element while the 1st one is halfway done, the 3rd while the 2nd it halfway done, etc.

I know I can do something like this:

```
$('#element1).fadeIn(1000);
$('#element2).delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
$('#element3).delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
etc.
```

A loop seems more elegant though and my question is, why doesn't the following code work as I would expect?

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++;) {
    $('#box' + i).fadeIn(2000).delay(500);
}
```

I would expect a delay to occur between each loop iteration, but instead all animation happens in sync.

Where am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: You accept questions by clicking the outlined checkmark next to the answer that best suits your question. You can accept one answer per question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every element has its own effects queue. For every element there must be different delay value:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $('#box' + (i + 1)).delay(500 * i).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cDcU7/1/

Comment: For instance, click the outlined checkmark next to this question to accept it as the best answer.

Comment: best answer for nested animations within a loop
like
for(...){
    $('element1').animate({...}, 800*i, function(){
          $(element2).animate(...)
     })